# Homomorphism between two groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I was solving some questions about homomorphism and isomorphism but then I made up a question. Here is the question: "If $\dfrac{G}{Ker(\phi)} \cong H$ then can we say there must be a homomorphism between $G$ and $H$?

$\underline{\text{Where does this question come from?}}$

I encountered a question on Bhattacharya's book:

> Show that a cyclic group of order 8 is homomorphic to a cyclic group of order 4

*Solution:*

Since these cyclic groups are finite I use the theorem saying every finite cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Consider the normal subgroup $\langle 4 \rangle$ of $\mathbb{Z}_8$. Hence we can consider Quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_8/\langle4\rangle$. A clear consequence of that is:
$$\mathbb{Z}_8/\langle4\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z_4}$$

So by First Isomorphism Theorem we can say there must be exist a homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_8$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathrm{Ker}(\phi)$ if you have not already assumed that you have a homomorphism? What is $\phi$?

Comment: My bad we can assume normal subgroup $N$ instead of $Ker(\phi)$

Comment: As I did in question

Comment: If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$,  and there is an isomorphism (a homomorphism would suffice) $f : G/N \to H$, just compose $f$ with the natural homomorphism $\pi : G \to G/N$ to get a homomorphism $G \to H$.

Comment: Every Quotient group of a group is a homomorphic image of the group can we say?

Comment: So to find all possible homomorphic images we just need to find normal subgroups of group and construct quotient groups respectively. Right?

Comment: @beingmathematician Yes, this is essentially the content of the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as was mentioned in the comments, the statement "$G/\text{ker} \phi \cong H$" has no meaning without first defining $\phi$. The proper question to ask would be if $G/N\cong H$ for some normal subgroup $N\trianglelefteq G$, does this imply that there is a homomorphism $\phi: G\rightarrow H$? The answer to this question is of course yes since we can compose with the canonical map $\pi:G \rightarrow G/N$ to obtain a map
$$ G\xrightarrow{\pi} G/N \xrightarrow{\cong} H$$

To determine all of the homomorphic images of a group $G$, we need only look at all the normal subgroups since these will correspond to the possible kernels of maps out of $G$.